# Dell Power Edge 2950 upgrade from 4GB to 32GB - says no memory

Tags: dell-poweredge, memory

I removed the original 4 x 1GB memory from our Dell Poweredge 2950 server (we have 2 Xeon quadcore processors).  I then added 8 x 4GB RAM.

When booting, the server gives a message saying no memory and boot abort. Also the message "Intrusion" comes at times.

When I put back the original 4 x 1GB, it works well.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Where did you get the memory? Is it memory specifically for the PE2950? Did you populate the DIMM slots according to the Dell documentation?

Comment: Did you entered the bios to see if server recognized them? can you plugin one of the new memory to try?

Comment: The obvious suggestion is that the memory you're adding is not compatible. Is it the exact same spec, other than capacity obviously, as the memory you've removed?

Comment: Dell servers invariably use ECC memory. And often Registered. Did you buy ECC memory and pay attention to the requirements?

Answer (score 4):

You have, most likely, purchased incompatible memory. When purchasing memory from a third party, you must verify that the voltage and rank are compatible as well as the total size of each module. Then, you must determine if your CPUs require buffered or unbuffered, ECC or non-ECC, etc.

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you didn't do all of this research. This is partially why DIMMs from the manufacturer are slightly more expensive - they're *guaranteed* to work and have been selected for your specific server.